# How to query result form given time range with MYSQL

Tags: mysql, timezone

front end is sending time range for that we need to query the teams.

```
create table teams (
  team_name varchar(255),
match_start_time time,
match_end_time time
);

insert into teams values 
("a",   "18:30",    "18:29"), 
("b",   "18:30",    "18:29"), 
("c",   "18:30",    "18:29"),
("d",   "18:30",    "18:29"),
("e",   "21:30",    "18:29"),
("f",   "19:30",    "18:29"),
("g",   "22:00",    "00:30"),
("h",   "23:30",    "00:30"),
("1",   "19:30",    "18:29"),
("j",   "21:30",    "13:30"),
("k",   "01:00",    "04:00"),
("l",   "09:30",    "18:30")

SELECT team_name,
TIME_FORMAT(match_start_time, "%H:%i") start_time,TIME_FORMAT(match_end_time, "%H:%i") end_time FROM teams 
WHERE 
match_start_time >= CAST('18:30:00' AS TIME)   
AND match_end_time <= CAST('21:30:00' AS TIME);


SELECT team_name,
TIME_FORMAT(match_start_time, "%H:%i") start_time,TIME_FORMAT(match_end_time, "%H:%i") end_time FROM teams 
WHERE 
match_start_time <= CAST('18:30:00' AS TIME)   
AND match_end_time <= CAST('21:30:00' AS TIME);
```

but here i am getting wrong result 
For 1st query result consists record for **team h**

- here 18:30 & 21:30 is UTC time which is 0:0 & 03:00 in IST 
  so for 2nd query getting **team k** in result which will convert to IST 05:30 & 9:30 but I want result for 0:00 to 03:00

[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9ZbuD7aCTpf8sXfeRd2anY/0)

Comment: It's decidedly odd to store information about *matches* in a table called *teams*.

Comment: @Strawberry we are not storing match data in teams table, it is match time for team means team is available to play match at this time.

Comment: So that would be a team_availabilty table, but hey, it's your party; obviously you can do what you like.